# Binding issue in Angular JS (Nested Variables)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

hope you're ok!

Well, basically my issue is related to binding a nested variable. As you can see in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abottoni/s7gn8/3/), I have a table and I need to have dynamic link in every column of it. So I create a Directive which create a `<a>` href element dinamically, that will depends on the data that will fill the table and in the table columns's definition.

This is the HTML code:

```
    <table ng-controller="MyCtrl" border=1 width="100%">
         <tr ng-repeat="item in dataGrid">
              <td ng-repeat="itemColumn in columnDefs" width="30%" style="text-align: center">
                    <link-cell-template columnitem="itemColumn" parentitem="item" />
              </td>
         </tr>
    </table>
```

And this is the directive code:

```
   myApp.directive('linkCellTemplate', function ($compile, $templateCache) {
       return {
           restrict: 'E',
           require: '?ngModel',
           replace: true,
           transclude: false,
           scope: {
               columnitem: '=',
               parentitem: '='
           },
           link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
               scope.hrefValue = angular.isDefined(scope.columnitem.linkUrl) ? scope.columnitem.linkUrl : "";
               scope.linkValue = angular.isDefined(scope.columnitem.linkDescription) ? scope.columnitem.linkDescription : scope.parentitem[scope.columnitem.field];
               // Append the HTML Layout in the Element
               element.append($compile($templateCache.get('linkCellTemplate.html'))(scope));
           }
       };
 }).run(["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
        $templateCache.put("linkCellTemplate.html",
             "<a href=\"{{hrefValue}}\" role=\"button\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">{{linkValue}}</a>");
 }]);
```

My directive is based in a template, and in the template I have two variables `{{hrefValue}}` and `{{linkValue}}` which values I handle inside the link function of the directive. The one that is giving me trouble is the `{{linkValue}}`, which according to the column definition, if the linkDescription attribute is not defined, It will take the column field attribute as a value, otherwise it will be the linkDescription.

The directive works fine with almost all the data. As you can see in the `$scope.dataGrid` variable, I have an array of associatives arrays. If you check the jsfiddle, you will find out that the 3rd column is defined to show the column field content (instead of the linkDescription) as the 2nd column is, but in this case, the link is not showed when you run it. After checking the code, I've found out that the problem is related to the field itself. In the 2nd column, the field is `Description`, but in the 3rd column is `Location.Name` (as it is in the dataGrid). That "Nested Variable" (Location.Name) is the one that is giving the problem.

I have been trying to find a way on how can I make my directive works with all type of fields (**Simple** as `Description` or **Nested** as `Location.Name`). Do you know what I'm missing? Any Idea will be helpful.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `$parse` for this cases (i.e. where there is a complex expression in the brackets). This is simple fortunately:

```
myApp.directive('linkCellTemplate', function ($compile, $templateCache, $parse) {
    ...
    scope.linkValue = angular.isDefined(scope.columnitem.linkDescription) ?
        scope.columnitem.linkDescription
        // here is the change
        : $parse(scope.columnitem.field)(scope.parentitem);
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikos. I didn't know about the `$parse`. Every day is a new day to learn new things ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not allow such constructions (and this is good imo):

```
object['one'].two.three != object['one.two'].three
```

Because `'one'` and `'one.two'` are different keys stored into hash table.

Fortunately, angularjs provides `$parse` for such manipulations. http://jsfiddle.net/s7gn8/4/

Comment: Thanks @werehuman. I didn't know about the `$parse`. Every day is a new day to learn new things ! Thanks !